# SocketTimedOut when connecting to https Url through CXF

Tags: java, cxf, socketexception

I am facing a problem with CXF framework trying to connect to a https backend service. Since the service is out side of my network I am using a proxy to connect. I am getting a SocketTimedOutException when I set the readTimeout Value to like 60000 which is the default. When I set the timeout to 0(infinite) it gives a connectionResetException after a while. I wrote a program on my own which used HttpsUrlConnection to connect to the same service with proxy and I am able to work with it.
I was initially under the feeling that the connection itself was not happening but later I came to know that that would have thrown a ConnectException rather than a socketException. It gave me some relief , but I want to know how I can deal with the SocketException, both the timeout and the Connection Reset.

Please explain to me whoever knows about this.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

You should blame on your network or your proxy, but not your codes. `SocketTimedOutException` and `ConnectionTimedOutException` are thrown when network is blocked or weak. So, the solution to both exceptions is smoothening your network.

Comment: I would not be so sure about this. One thing because I wrote a standalone application which used HttpsUrlConnection to connect to the same backend. And it works fine.

Comment: The only difference between my application and the application in question is that the CXF framework is configuring SSLSocketFactory, within HttpsUrlConnection which I am not doing. This seems to be causing the issue, but beyond this I am not sure what exactly is happening.